# In Star Trek, what uses would an astrophysics lab have for a stasis unit?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, technology, stasis

At the beginning of [TNG: Starship Mine](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starship_Mine_(episode)), Captain Picard tells Dr.  Beverly Crusher to arrange with Geordi La Forge to beam a stasis unit from the ship's astrophysics lab.

**Why would an astrophysics lab have a stasis unit?** Is there any other time in Star Trek where a stasis unit is mentioned in relation to astrophysics that would shed light on the applications of such a device in that field of research?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/244.txt) makes it clear that the [stasis unit](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Stasis_chamber) Picard has requested isn't *normally* intended for medical use but is in fact some manner of scientific study apparatus (perhaps for storing gases or samples from nebulae) and that the unit can be jerry-rigged to work as a crude medical [stasis chamber](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/File:Stasis_chamber_sketch.jpg), presumably because they both work on the same scientific principles;

> **BEVERLY :** *Captain... Arkaria Base does not have the medical storage units I requested. I have seven living tissue samples that
>   won't survive the baryon sweep anymore than you or I would. I've tried
>   to reason with them, but --*
>
> **PICARD :** *Have Mister LaForge transport a stasis unit from the astrophysics lab. You should be able to convert it to store tissue
>   samples.*

The key word here is *convert.*

The excellent (and moderately canon) [Star Trek TNG Technical Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Star_Fleet_Technical_Manual) indicates that "stasis" technology works by slowing atomic motion, something which would be invaluable in the study of various forms of matter and antimatter found in astrophysical phenomena;

> *The technology that has given rise to the QCRD is similar to that of the transporter, SIF, IDF, and other devices that manipulate matter on
>   the quantum level. The conversion process sees the inlet of normal
>   matter, stretched out into thin rivulets no more than 0.000003 cm
>   across. The rivulets are pressure-fed into the QCRD under magnetic
>   suspension, where groups of them are chilled to within 0.001 degree of
>   absolute zero, and exposed to a short-period stasis field to **further
>   limit molecular vibration**. As the stasis field decays, focused
>   subspace fields drive deep within the subatomic structure to flip the
>   charges and spins of the "frozen" protons, neutrons, and electrons.
>   The flipped matter, now antimatter, is magnetically removed for
>   storage. The system can normally process 0.08 m<sup>3</sup>/hr.*

Comment: "convert" could mean taking out the test tube rack and putting in a petri dish rack in instead.

Comment: True, but I'm guessing it'll involve getting laforge to route the auxiliary "tech" to the primary "tech"; http://www.blastr.com/2009/10/ron_moore_calls_star_trek.php

Comment: incidentally this seems to suggest that anti-matter production is a lot more efficient than I previously thought!

Comment: @Michael - Assuming the right circumstances, the ship can manufacture its own torpedoes. Voyager did this.

Comment: Right, but I didn't realize it could be done without expending an amount of energy equal to mc^2 where m is the mass of the anti-matter created.

Comment: @Michael - Well, we don't know how much energy is required, nor for how long the unit can remain in operation.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of any other references to similar situations in the show, but it seems fairly straightforward to me.  Anyone studying physics, especially physics in the wild-and-wacky world of deep space in *Star Trek*, would find it useful to be able to freeze a sample or an experiment for storage or detailed study.

Astrophysics specifically might be keeping a space-based life form in stasis, or (depending on the meaning of "stasis") something more like a transporter pattern of some strange object or material.  Or perhaps it's for producing rare materials in a lab: in the real world, many experimental elements only exist for a fraction of a second.  Maybe a stasis pod slows down the atom's decay so it can be studied.  Or it could be something only tangentially related to Astrophysics, like a storage capsule for an eminent physicist who is being held in stasis for some reason.

Since it's just a passing remark in that episode I doubt there is an "official use" detailed in the canon, but the possibilities seem varied enough that we can extrapolate that they have them around just in case a need arises.